# How do I use the map reduce function in Python to determine a value?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

Below is a list of data on foods you might find at a grocery store.
The CSV file below denote the city, food type, average price per pound, and the meal in which that food is consumed in for a city in California. I need to determine using the Map reduce function in python which food type has the lowest total price per pound.

```
Los Angeles,Vegetables,25.51,Breakfast
San Francisco,Fruits,259.32,Breakfast
Sandiego,Meat,22.94,Lunch
Sacramento,Dairy,53.71,Dinner
San Jose,Fish,44.16,Snack
Fresno,Poultry,393.05,Brunch
Oakland,Vegetables,15.99,Dinner
Bakersfield,Nuts,201.46,Dinner
Long Beach,Poultry,74.6,Snack
Anaheim,Grains,89.6,Breakfast
Riverside,Meat,152.75,Brunch
Irvine,Poultry,88.99,Brunch
Santa Barbara,Dairy,241.26,Lunch
Pasadena,Beans,789.7,Snack
```

Here is what I have so far. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class LowestPrice(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        line_cols = line.split(',')
        yield line_cols[1], 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LowestPrice.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas for this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/shrek/Documents/data.csv', header=None)

print(data[2].min())
index = data[data[2]== data[2].min()].index[0]
print(data[1][index]+"in "+data[0][index]+" used in "+data[3][index]+" has lowest price per pound = "+str(data[2].min()))
```

the output will be :

```
Vegetablesin Oakland used in Dinner has lowest price per pound = 15.99
```

Comment: use this code inside a function that and call this in your map reduce script